# Trying to print out the "best customer" who has the largest amount spent

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, max

Here's what I've got so far. I can get the highest amount printed out but I can't figure out how to connect the customer name to the sale they had, and then to print their name with their total.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW5 {
public static void nameOfBestCustomer(ArrayList<Double> sales,
    ArrayList<String> customers) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> sales = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> customer = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[][] BestCustomer = new int[1][10];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Total Number of Customers: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name of customer " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
        customer.add(in.next());

        System.out.print("Total amount for customer " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
        sales.add(in.nextDouble());
    }

    double maximum = Collections.max(sales);
    System.out.println("The Best Customer is " + customer
            + "with a purchase of ");
    System.out.println(String.format("$%.2f", maximum));
}
}
```

Comment: Covered custom objects yet? I'm assuming HW5 is Homework 5?

Comment: Since you are using parallel lists, use your highest amount to get the corresponding index of the customer list.

Comment: Use a loop to go over the values in sales. If you found the max sale, then save that index `i`. Then print out both the customer at that index and the sale at that index.  `sales.get(i)` and `customer.get(i)` sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "parallel" lists, that is, two separate lists expected to correspond 1:1 to eachother:

```
ArrayList<Double> sales = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> customer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

As you are learning, this comes with some difficulties as far as managing information goes. If you want to keep using these lists, the best approach is to identify a customer + sale collectively by their *index* in the lists. `Collections.max()` will only return the maximum *value*, not the index, so it is up to you to manually implement that logic. Assuming your lists are not empty, an algorithm for that is generally (implementation is for you to work out):

1. Initially assume highest item is first item in the list, so index of highest item is initially 0.
2. For each of the remaining items, if that item is greater than the highest item, set the new highest item index to that item's index.

Now you can use the index of the highest item as the index into both of your arrays.

However, the better way to do this would be to create a small custom class to hold all the information about a sale in one place. For example:

```
static class Transaction {
    double sale;
    String customer;
}
```

Now you can maintain a single array:

```
ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

Store transactions in that array:

```
Transaction t = new Transaction();
t.sale = ...;
t.customer = ...;
transactions.add(t);
```

Then you have to have a way of comparing two `Transaction`s; your options are either:

1. Have `Transaction` implement [`Comparable<Transaction>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or
2. Define a [`Comparator<Transaction>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that can compare sale amounts.

I'll leave the details of those as an exercise to you - check out the official tutorial on [object ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html), it is short, concise, and contains good examples. Once you do that, you now have the infrastructure in place to use `Collections.max()` (either the [version that takes a `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)) for option 2, or the [version that doesn't](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) for option 1), and `max()` will now directly return the `Transaction` object, which contains both the amount and the customer name.

Comment: Thank you very much!I think I'm starting to understand what to do but just in case could you possibly check part of my new code?
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter name of customer " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
    t.customer = customer.add(in.next());
    System.out.print("Total amount for customer " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
t.sale = sales.add(in.nextDouble());
transactions.add(t);
Comparator<Transaction>;
ArrayList<Transaction> maximum = (transactions);
System.out.println("The Best Customer is " + " with a purchase of ");
System.out.println(String.format("$%.2f", maximum));